# Call function after boolean variable changes to false in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, window-resize

I have **multiple carousels** in single HTML using Object Oriented approach in ES5. The sliders slide automatically each in different time interval. During resize, I have function `resizeEverything()` that resizes all the components in slider. But the issue is when I resize the window, the orientation of image gets disturbed.

The technique I use to build the carousel is

```
var moving=true;
setInterval(()=>{
  //subtract wrapper.style.left by small factor until imageWidth
  //clear Interval once destination has arrived and set moving=false
}
```

Now after resizing I want to reset the position to `currentIndex`'s **style.left** when *moving becomes false*.

I have tried some of the promise methods which doesn't seem to work.

```
    resizeEverything();
    for(var i=0; i<carouselObjects.length; i++){

        new Promise(function(resolve = ()=>{
            wrappers[i].style.left = -(carouselObjects[i].currentIndex*carouselObjects[i].imageWidth);
        }, reject = ()=>{
            console.log("PROMISE ERROR");
        }){
            var myInterval = setInterval(()=>{
                if(carouselObjects[i].moving==false){
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                    resolve();
                }
            },500);
        });
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are not returning the promise

Comment: I assume you mean `var moving = true;`, not `val ...`.

Comment: Also, why are you assing values to `resolve` and `reject` in the promise function?

Comment: Ghassen sir. could you help me with proper way of doing it?

Comment: I don't see a reason to involve promises here. You know exactly when `moving` becomes `false`, you control the code that does the assignment. Just put your position-resetting stuff in there as well.